# Modify list using multiple def functions

Tags: python, list, user-defined-functions

Hello hopefully someone can steer me in the right direction.

I am trying to figure out how use def function to modify lines of text in a list according to user input. eg if user enters "a", it adds a line to the list, "d" = delete line and so on...

I have defined the functions and know what they have to do, here is some of it:

```
lineList = []
lines = ""

##Add Line
def addLine ():
    while lines != "#":
        lines = input ("Add a line: ")
        lineList.append(lines)
    for (i, item) in enumerate(lineList, start=1):
        print(str(i)+":", item)            


##Delete Line
def deleteLine ():
    lineNum = int(input("Enter line: ")    )
    del lineList[(lineNum)]
    for (i, item) in enumerate(lineList, start=1):
        print(str(i)+":", item)

##Find and replace string
def findReplace ():
    findString = input("Find string: ")
    replaceString = input ("Replace with: ")
    for n, i in enumerate(lineList):
        if i == findString:
            lineList[n] = replaceString
    for (i, item) in enumerate(lineList, start=1):
        print(str(i)+":", item)
```

So I am trying to find out: should the initial list be inside addLine () or outside it? Should I use addLine() to just append the list? Also how do the other functions access the list to make changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the functions accept the current `lineList` as a parameter and return it back after changes. For example:

```
##Add Line
def addLine(lineList):
    lines = ""
    while lines != "#":
        lines = input ("Add a line: ")
        lineList.append(lines)
    for (i, item) in enumerate(lineList, start=1):
        print(str(i)+":", item)  

    return lineList


##Delete Line
def deleteLine(lineList):
    lineNum = int(input("Enter line: "))
    del lineList[(lineNum)]
    for (i, item) in enumerate(lineList, start=1):
        print(str(i)+":", item)

    return lineList

##Find and replace string
def findReplace(lineList):
    findString = input("Find string: ")
    replaceString = input ("Replace with: ")
    for n, i in enumerate(lineList):
        if i == findString:
            lineList[n] = replaceString
    for (i, item) in enumerate(lineList, start=1):
        print(str(i)+":", item)

    return lineList


lineList = []
while True:
    command = input("Enter command (a, d, f): ")
    if command == "a":
        lineList = addLine(lineList)
    elif command == "d":
        lineList = deleteLine(lineList)
    elif command == "f":
        lineList = findReplace(lineList)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood what u are trying to do u need to have the linelist variable outside the functions so it is a global variable and then u can access it from everywhere even inside functions. if u declare that variable inside the function add u will need to add at the beginning of the add function:

```
def addLine ():
    global linelist
    linelist = []
    while lines != "#":
        lines = input ("Add a line: ")
        lineList.append(lines)
    for (i, item) in enumerate(lineList, start=1):
         print(str(i)+":", item)
```

this way the variable is global aswell, but it is easier to use it just outside the function.

> hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you just make your functions take the list as function parameters. It's generally bad practice to use global variables, and you should avoid them whenever possible. That way, your functions can be self-contained and independant, which is a good design trait. So, just make it an argument instead.

Also, the following block of code is redundant in every function of yours. It'd be better if you just encapsulate it inside of a function too.

```
for (i, item) in enumerate(lineList, start=1):
        print(str(i)+":", item)
```

For example:

```
def print_lines(line_list):
    for (i, item) in enumerate(lineList, start=1):
        print(str(i)+":", item)
```

This way, you don't have to worry about the for loop everytime, and can just have `print_lines(line_list)` in your functions instead.

Protip: Have a look at the [PEP-8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). This PEP will give you some insight on how you should style your code.

Hope the answer helped :)